# Make bash wait until remote server kickstart is done (it will create a file when it's done)

Tags: bash

I am creating a script to kickstart several servers. I am nearly finished, however I want the bash script to wait until the server kickstart is done.

When the kickstart is done and the server is rebooted a file will be created on the remote kickstarted server which is located under "**/root/**" and is called "**kickstart-DONE**"

Is it possible to make the bash script wait until it sees this file and then post something like "Done!"...?

I tried searching the forums and internet, but probably I am searching incorrectly, as I was unable to find something relevant to this issue. Heck, I don't even know if this is possible at all.

So in short; I run my script which kickstarts a server. After the kickstart is done it will create a file on the remote (- kickstarted) server called: kickstart-DONE. This would be an indication for the script that the kickstart is fully done and the server can be used. How do I make the script aware of this?

I hope someone understands what I mean and trying to achieve....

Thanks in advance.

//EDIT

SOLVED! Thanks to Cole Tierney!

Cole Tierney gave some good answers, however though it works it does not wait until the server is kickstarted. I ran the script to kickstart a server and in the end it was running the provided command:

```
ssh root@$HWNODEIP "while ! test -e /root/kickstart-DONE; do sleep 3; done; echo KICKSTART IS DONE...\!"
```

However since the kickstart can take some time (depending on server speed and such; ranging from 15 minutes to 1 hour). The command timed out:

> ssh: connect to host 100.125.150.175 port 22: Connection timed out

Is there a way that the script does not time out at all and keeps it alive until the server gets back or until it takes more than 1 hour or so?

Maybe there is also a way to make it show that the script is still active? Like "Waiting... 5 minutes passed." "Waiting... 10 minutes passed." etc.

So it gives the current user some information that it not died?

Comment: To rule out connection problems, are you able to ssh to the server? If so, I would recommend using setting up an ssh host entry in `~/.ssh/config`. You could then tune you ssh options without having a super long ssh command. I'll add an example to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call `sleep` until the file exists:

```
while ! test -e /root/kickstart-DONE; do sleep 3; done; echo kickstart done
```

Or sleep until the server is accepting ssh connections. Run the following netcat command locally to check when port 22 is open on the server (remove `echo closed;` if you don't want the extra feedback):

```
while ! nc -zw2 $HWNODEIP 22; do echo closed; sleep 3; done
```

On a side note, it's useful to setup a host entry in `~/.ssh/config`. You can add all sorts of ssh options here without making your ssh command unwieldy. Options that are common to all host entries can be added outside of the host entries. See `man ssh_config` for other options. Here's an example (server1 can be anything, replace <server ip> with the server's ip address):

```
Host server1
    Hostname <server ip>
    User root
```

Then to use it:

```
ssh server1 'some command'
```

Note that many systems will not allow ssh connections from root for security reasons. You may want to consider adding another user for kickstart stuff. Add this user to sudoers if root access is needed.

Comment: Thank you for answering, so is the correct usage for remote:

ssh root@$HWNODEIP "while ! test -e /root/kickstart-DONE; do sleep 3; done; echo kickstart done!"

Uhm. I guess not; I am getting "-bash: !": event not found"-error. Guess I will take another look and experiment a little?

Comment: I tried moving some stuff around, but it doesn't work. I am getting that same bash error. :(

Comment: You could test it, but that looks like it should work. Or you could make it a script on $HWNODEIP and maybe add a timeout in case something goes wrong.

Comment: See my first comment; error is mentioned in there. Will also update my main post.

Comment: I see the error now. Try escaping the exclamation point or remove it. Bash thinks it's a history command

Comment: Actually it's not solved... :( I will update my main post with more information.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an ssh config example and a note about connecting as root

Comment: Just occurred to me that the sshd service would not be available until the server has completed restarting. So maybe the thing to do is to wait until port 22 is accepting connections. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I've added a port 22 check to my answer

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Cole; I was at Oktoberfest in Munich, so couldn't respond earlier. Will give the new solution a go. Thank you kindly for your help and explanation!

Comment: You're welcome. Oktoberfest in Munich definitely take precedence!